# Using ImageMagick to repeat or "tile" an image

Tags: image, imagemagick, tile, montage

How do I tile an image using ImageMagick?  I don't think I can use `montage` because I want the columns displaced by 50% of the original image height.

It's probably easier to show an example of what I'm trying to do:

Start with:

[image]

End with:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to Fred at [Fred's ImageMagick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php), here's the solution:

```
infile="tile.png"

h2=`convert $infile -format "%[fx:round(h/2)]" info:`

convert $infile \( -clone 0 -roll +0+$h2 \) +append -write mpr:sometile +delete -size 1000x500 tile:mpr:sometile output.png
```

This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 32):

In case you want plain tiles, without shifting down the second column and the rest of the even columns, you can use this script:

```
convert -size 800x600 tile:Ball.jpg Tiles.jpg
```

(probably the majority of people landing on this question want such plain tiles, like I did)

My "Ball.jpg" is 200 x 200 pixels, so this script creates a 4x3 tile image.

For ImageMagick 7 users, replace convert with magick.

Comment: same usage on linux: `convert -size 800x600  tile:Ball.jpg Tiles.jpg`

Comment: @MarinosAn funny that `tile:` cannot come before `-size` ?

Comment: @Rodrigo I guess it's because the `tile` [pseudo-image format](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#pseudo) is specified as prefix in the filename. And according to convert manpage, input filename should be placed before input options: `convert [input-option] input-file [output-option] output-file`

Comment: Can you add a border around the tiles ? Like montage's `-geometry` option

Answer (score 9):

Even though you did not mention anything about context of usage, I will put it here so more people are aware. [Fred's](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php) scripts are for **non-commercial** use. I ended with an alternative solution, however, principle is the same:

1. Creating shifted tile by:

   `convert _orange_270.jpg -roll +0+135 _orange_270_r.jpg`
2. Create a column of regular tiles:

   `montage _orange_270.jpg +clone +clone +clone -tile x4 -geometry +0+0 _1col.jpg`
3. Create a column of shifted tiles:

   `montage _orange_270_r.jpg +clone +clone +clone -tile x4 -geometry +0+0 _2col.jpg`
4. Combined regular and shifted columns:

   `montage -geometry +0+0 _1col.jpg _2col.jpg _2cols.jpg`
5. Created full tiled image using last output from point 4:

   `convert _2cols.jpg -write mpr:tile  +delete -size 1920x1080 tile:mpr:tile _wallpap.jpg`

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If on a unix-like system with ImageMagick, you could just use my script, tileimage at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tileimage/index.php.

It provides numerous variations on the flipping, rotation and offsets.

If non-commercial use, then it is free, If commercial use, then contact me for a license.

Information about tiling in ImageMagick can found at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#tile